# Elasticsearch index/cache not clearing/stuck

Tags: node.js, caching, indexing, elasticsearch, firebase

I'm using https://github.com/firebase/flashlight to index data for searches

However, this morning I deleted the whole firebase index, so it should be empty (this has worked before, but it seems that when the nodejs app.js crashes in some cases, causing the cache to get "stuck"), but I still see old search results from my nodejs app somehow...

I've tried:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear
```

and

```
http://localhost:9200/_flush
http://localhost:9200/firebase/_flush
```

They all say successful, but still I get `old results`, out of, seemingly nowhere.

I can also see in the console that it refreshes every 60 seconds, and, deleting the whole firebase has worked before without problems...

I even saw a message `housekeeping: found 60 orphans (removing them now)` in the console so it should be refreshed by now...

I tried restarting elasticsearch as well as the whole Linux/Debian server...

In the config.js I have two indexes:

```
exports.paths = [
   {
      path:  "tags",
      index: "firebase",
      type:  "tag",
      filter: function(data) { return data.name !== 'system'; }
   },
   {
      path:  "tracks",
      index: "firebase",
      type:  "track",
      filter: function(data) { return data.name !== 'system'; }
   }
];
```

And strangely enough, I have no problem whatsoever when using the 'track' store, instead of using the 'tag' one...

What am I missing here?

// Update !

So, I just deleted the firebase `tracks` index while the nodejs script was running and the script `crashed`... Same problem, different index. So the `crashing script must cause it`... so, how do I `clear this stuck cache`?

Comment: If you have restarted flashlight's worker process, it will re-index all those values from the data upon restarting, thereby putting them back into ES.

Comment: Well, it doesn't, i even rebooted the whole server, desperately. It shows results, that are not existant in the firebase at all. It's like somehow the cache got stuck for the specific 'tag' index...

Comment: So, I just deleted the firebase `tracks` index while the nodejs script was running and the script crashed... Guess what? Same problem, different index. So the crashing script must cause it...

Comment: When you say that you are deleting the index, do you mean that you are deleting them in ElasticSearch? Why would you do that while you have a script trying to put data into the index?

Comment: "firebase `tracks` index", so just deleting the whole tree in `Firebase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it by simply doing:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/Firebase
```

Thanks to: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/7541#issuecomment-54724302

I'm guessing Elastic search is not aware (and has not been told) of the relevance of its current index, perhaps the Flashlight script I'm using is not informing it about what the index should have been? But, since this is only necessary when the node script crashes when you suddenly delete your whole firebase index, it should be catchable somehow, but I'm happy that I can at least fix it like this. Rebuilding the index is not a big issue/task right now, but in the future it might be.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, maybe you are not posting the queries correctly. You said you have tried following links:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear
http://localhost:9200/_flush
http://localhost:9200/firebase/_flush
```

If you are accessing the urls from browser it won't clear them. You have to POST them. It is ambiguous from your question if you did it, both GET and POST return same results (showing total, successful and failed). Try this from commandline using curl:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_flush'
```

Or create an AJAX request with JQuery or use fiddler.

Comment: I really hoped that was it, but it still pulls results out of its *** after that... And it really seems that the crashing of the node script causes it...

Comment: If only I could find out where this cache is saved, I'm beginning to suspect that nodejs has some cache somewhere. And I mean, I'm 100% sure that if I were to format the drive (;P) that would fix it, or install it on a different machine. But I just want to know how to fix it manually...

Comment: Barring miracles (and cloud storage), `nodejs` has to *read* its data from the disk. It *has* to do so using standard I/O. So if you ran `nodejs` under `strace -f`, it would give you a *huge* list with all files used by `nodejs` for whatever reason. `... 2>&1 | grep "^open(" | grep -v ENOENT | cut -f2 -d'"' | sort | uniq ` will greatly reduce the number of lines you need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimize your indeces by sending the following POST request to your elasticsearch server:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_optimize?max_num_segments=1&wait_for_merge=true'
```

It makes lucene really delete the deleted documents from disk and merge indeces.